# Make multiple collapse using ui.bootstrap and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to make `ui bootstrap collapse`. When I'm using static single or double collapse system, its working fine, but for my design I'm using `ng-repeat` to create collapse, so I have no idea how to use multiple collapse,

I found this code, but it will only work for static code,

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
  app.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.trafficCollapsed = false;
   $scope.urlCollapsed = false;
   $scope.toggleUrl = function () {
   $scope.urlCollapsed = false;
   $scope.trafficCollapsed = !$scope.trafficCollapsed
 };
  $scope.toggleTraffic = function () {
  $scope.trafficCollapsed = false;
  $scope.urlCollapsed = !$scope.urlCollapsed;
 };
});
```

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>/<span class="pull-right" ng-click="toggleUrl()">&#x25BC;</span></td>
    <td>A beautiful title</td>
    <td>A beautiful description</td>
    <td>54,654<span class="pull-right" ng-click="toggleTraffic()">&#x25BC;</span
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want this design to be collapse.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, this may help you.
[here is working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/xv7tws10/31/)

```
  <body ng-app="my_app">
  <div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
  <ul class="nav">
      <li ng-repeat="(key,val) in menuArray">
      <button class="btn" ng-click="val.isMenuCollapsed = !val.isMenuCollapsed">{{val.button}}
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-links" collapse="val.isMenuCollapsed">
        <li ng-repeat="link in val.links" role="menuitem">
          <a href="#">{{link.title}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Style

```
    .nav>li {
    display: inline !important;
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown-links{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}
```

Controller code

```
var my_app = angular.module('my_app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

my_app.controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.menuArray = [
   {'button':'Button1','isMenuCollapsed':true,'links':[{'title':'link1-1'},{'title':'link1-2'}]},
   {'button':'Button2','isMenuCollapsed':true,'links':[{'title':'link2-1'},{'title':'link2-2'}]}
 ];
  console.log($scope.menuArray);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but 1st I need `collapse` not `dropdown` https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse, 2nd I need one open at time not all. @DevidasKadam

Comment: you can add any markup in collapse, I just added dropdown menu. I will update fiddle and answer to keep one open at a time.

Comment: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/xv7tws10/32/) is the updated fiddle, you can just take an idea from this example and develop your own. finally you are a developer.

Comment: did you noticed that I used `collapse="val.isMenuCollapsed"`, you can add any markup in `ul` or you can use a `div` having attribute `collapse`.